# FTP client-Android Image corrupted

Tags: android, apache, ftp, ftp-client

I'm trying to implement FTP Java library on my Android app to upload images to FTP server

The library is the 3.4 version of apache-commons-net.

The problem is when the image  is uploaded, the file is corrupted and is not possible to show it.

This is part of code.

First connect to server and configure it, (works fine)

```
public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,
                          String password, int port)
{
    try {
        mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
        mFTPClient.connect(host, port);

        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {

            boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);
            mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            return status;
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host );
    }

    return false;
}
```

And then upload a file and show progress

public boolean ftpUpload()
{

```
boolean finalizado = false;
String destDir="";

try {
    mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();


    while(mFilesUploaded < f.size() && !cancel){

    tmpFile = f.get(mCurrentFileIndex);

    String[] fileAux2 = tmpFile.getName().split("\\(");
    String[] parentAux = tmpFile.getParent().split("\\/");
    System.out.println(tmpFile.getName());


    if(isBackup){

        if(parentAux[parentAux.length - 1].equals("databases")) {destDir ="Backup/db";}
        else { destDir ="Backup/data/" + parentAux[parentAux.length - 1];}      

    }
    else{ destDir = "/"+fileAux2[0]; }

    System.out.println(destDir + " -> " + checkDirectoryExists(destDir));

    if(!checkDirectoryExists(destDir)) ftpCreateDirectoryTree(destDir);
    else ftpChangeDirectory(destDir);

    String filePath = destDir + "/" + tmpFile.getName();



    //if(checkFileExists(filePath)) {System.out.println("intento eliminar " + ftpRemoveFile(filePath));}

    InputStream srcFileStream = new FileInputStream(tmpFile);
    OutputStream out = mFTPClient.storeFileStream(tmpFile.getName());

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    int allRead = 0;

    while( ( ( read = srcFileStream.read( buffer ) ) != - 1 )  && !cancel) {
        allRead += read;                
        Double porcentaje =  ((double) allRead / (double)tmpFile.length()) * 100;
        publishProgress((int) Math.round(porcentaje));              
        out.write( buffer, 0, read );

    }

    srcFileStream.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    if(read == -1 && mFTPClient.completePendingCommand() && !cancel){
        publishProgress(100);
        mFilesUploaded++;
        mCurrentFileIndex++;

        }
    else{
        publishProgress(-1);

    }

    }
            if(cancel == true){cancel = false; finalizado = false;}
            else finalizado = true;

            mCurrentFileIndex = 0;
            mFilesUploaded = 0;                 
            ftpDisconnect(); 


} 
catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

return finalizado;
```

}

**EDIT:** When the file is uploaded his size is less than the original size.(`mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)` is configured).

If I reduce the byte size of `byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];` the size of the file increases but the time of upload is too slow

Someone can help me?

Comment: Don't know what goes wrong but I use: InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(FileName); mFTPClient.storeFile(PictName, instream); In which way is your file corrupted?

Comment: The image file seems correct but when try to open I can't do it.
I use `storeFileStream` because I need show the progress of upload.

One question, If I need to upload several images, Where have to use `mFTPClient.completePendingCommand()`?

Comment: After every upload i would say. Please explain more about the corruptness of your file.

Comment: When I try to open the imagefile,(in a ftpserver or downloading the uploaded file) the file not shows, Windows image viewer says that the image file is corrupted o is too big

Comment: I've updated the original code with the last modifications

Also, if try to upload two files, when the first image is uploaded (after in and out.close) I check if `mFTPClient.completePendingCommand()`, then proceed to upload the second image but when the code try to `OutputStream out = mFTPClient.storeFileStream(tmpFile.getName());` returns `null` and stops the execution. What is wrong?

Comment: You never break out of the loop when something goes wrong. Even if completePendingCommand() is false you will try to upload the same image again. if ( read==-1) well if read is not -1 you try to upload the image again too. Do an out.flush() before out.close(). What sense does it make to try to upload more files as the first one is already corrupted? Try to find out the filesize of the uploaded image and compare with original.

Comment: Hi, In fact the size of uploaded file is less than original file. I don't understand, `mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)` is configured. On the other hand if I reduce the buffer size in `byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];` the data loss is reduced i.e `new byte[2]` the download is correct but the upload time is to slow. Any idea?

Comment: If you keep the buffer at [1024] then is the uploaded file size a multiple of 1024? Please be exact. In your upload loop what is the value of allRead at the end? Compare to filesize.

Comment: Yes, is a multiple of 1024 least the last read. The value of allRead is less than the original file size. If increases the buffersize the resulstant file is more small. I tested with 2 bytes on buffersize and the resultant file is 2 bytes less than original file

Comment: What was the exact value of AllRead? A multiple of 1024? Equal on uploaded file size? Please be exact!!!! What are the individual values of read? Is read always 1024?

Comment: I've solved the problem, In my code before enter in `while( ( ( read = srcFileStream.read( buffer ) ) != - 1 ))` had a print with `srcFileStream.read( buffer )`... I'm sorry for wasting your time.